# Perl Programming Exercise - How do I Compare ASCII Values?

Tags: perl, if-statement, ascii

I wrote the following program to test Perl's ability to evaluate ASCII values, and its `if` / `elsif` statements.

I want to avoid using the language's sort function.

```
#test ASCII values using if and elsif
$s = '4';
$j = 'a';
$k = "AS";

#1st print the variable with the lowest ASCII value
if ($s <= $j && $s <= $k) {
    say $s;
    $s = 1000;
} elsif ($j <= $s && $j <= $k) {
    say $j;
    $j = 1000;
} elsif ($k <= $j && $k <= $s) {
    say $k;
    $k = 1000;
}

#print the variable with the 2nd lowest value
if ($s <= $j && $s <= $k) {
    say $s;
    $s = 1000;
} elsif ($j <= $s && $j <= $k) {
    say $j;
    $j = 1000;
} elsif ($k <= $j && $k <= $s) {
    say $k;
    $k = 1000;
}

#print the variable with the 3nd lowest value
if ($s <= $j && $s <= $k) {
    say $s;
    $s = 1000;
} elsif ($j <= $s && $j <= $k) {
    say $j;
    $j = 1000;
} elsif ($k <= $j && $k <= $s) {
    say $k;
    $k = 1000;
}
```

My output is as follows:

```
52
97
65
a
AS
4
```

but the correct outcome is:

```
52
97
65
4
AS
a
```

Thank you in advance. Tips on how to improve my question writing are welcome.

Comment: Turn on strict and warnings and you'll see that you're trying to do numeric comparisons on non-numeric characters. So,  "use strict;"  and "use warnings;"  and declare your vars as "my $s; " etc.  Then when you run it you'll see the warnings.  Checkout perldoc perlop for comparison operators.

Comment: I'm confused. Where do `52`, `97`, and `65` come from? They are the ordinal values of the first character of your inputs `4`, `a`, and `AS`, but I don't see where you compute them. Anyway, Perl has two sets of comparison operators. `<`, `<=`, `==`, `!=`, `>`, `>=`, `<=>` for numerical comparison, and `lt`, `le`, `eq`, `ne`, `ge`, `gt`, `cmp` for lexical (string) comparison. See [`perldoc perlop`](http://metacpan.org/pod/perlop).

Comment: In other words, if you wish to get ASCII (and compute with it, by using `==, <, >` operators), you need to convert the strings.  You can do that with `ord` or `unpack`, for example. (And it seems that you have done that somehow since you show that in "output" -- so _show complete examples_.)  While Perl does allow us to store either a number or a string in a scalar variable, when it comes to using them you can't always expect things to just work regardless.

Comment: // , You have asked a good question, Mr. McNulty. Welcome to the misery! Please consider showing us some of the research you've already done on this topic, and applying Tim Bunce's answer to a question about "linting", here, to the code example you have so helpfully provided us: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27133639/2146138

Comment: The code you show won't even compile, as you haven't defined `say` anywhere. Once that is fixed the output is `a`, `AS`, `4` and not the text that you show. We can't possibly help you unless you explain your problem accurately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always use `use strict; use warnings;`! The latter would have told you that you were using numerical comparison operators (e.g. `<`) where you should be using string comparison operators (e.g. `lt`).

But you could simply use the following:

```
say for sort $s, $j, $k;
```

Comment: Yes, your are correct. Thank you, and thanks to the other folks as well. I was using numerical comparisons when I should have been using string comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `ord` function to obtain the numeric value of the first character of the argument.  This is per-character, not per-byte, which means that Unicode works correctly.  http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ord.html for more information.